# Serilog section in a yaml file - how to configure Encoding to UTF8

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog

After perusing the web and not finding any answers.

Using

```
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="3.2.0" /><PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="4.1.0" />
```

I'm using Serilog and I've put the configuration in the yaml file like so :

```
Serilog:
  Using:
  - Serilog.Sinks.Console
  - Serilog.Sinks.File
  MinimumLevel:
    Default: Warning
    Override:
        Microsoft: Warning
        System: Warning
  WriteTo:
  - Name: Console
  - Name: File
    Args:
      path: 'D:\APPLFICH\log\xnt-annotation-notifications-log-.txt'
      rollingInterval: Day
      rollOnFileSizeLimit: true
      fileSizeLimitBytes: 5000000
      retainedFileCountLimit: 100
      encoding: UTF8
  Enrich:
  - FromLogContext
  - WithMachineName
  - WithThreadId
```

Backend :

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddYamlFile("appsettings.yml")
            .Build();            

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                 .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                 .CreateLogger();

//Add logging
services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
{
   loggingBuilder.AddSerilog();
});
```

Now I'm getting this error :

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Text.Encoding'.'
```

Also the Default log level is ignored in the console but not the file

Hence the following questions :

- How can I specify Endoding UTF8 into the yaml ?

Comment: You can do like this in program.cs:`Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
               .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
               .WriteTo.File(path: @".\Log\Log.txt",     
                   rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,   
                   rollOnFileSizeLimit: true,             
                   encoding: Encoding.UTF8,                
                   retainedFileCountLimit: 10,              
                   fileSizeLimitBytes: 10 * 1024)                
               .CreateLogger();`

Comment: I know, I want to avoid that. I want the config in the yml to drive everything.